# How to Stop AWS aurora cluster using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code, aws-aurora-serverless

I have set up Aurora regional clustor with terrafrm with one writer instance. But I am not currently using it as it is not needed at the moment, therefore I want to stop it using terraform.
In aws console i cant see that i can stop it but temporarily for 7 days and then it will be started again.I want to stop it using terraform unless i want it back.

```
Is there any property that i can use in terraform to acheive this ?
```

Comment: do you stop or destroy?

Comment: i have to stop and not destroy so that unnecessary charges will be skipped

Comment: I am not aware of anyway to achieve that via terraform directly. you could possibly use a local provisioner to call the awsapi with something like `aws rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier mydbinstance` there you could get your details from your terraform resoruce

Comment: but remember this is only a temporary stop, AWS will auto start it after 7 days no matter what you do as quoted in thier docs `You can stop a DB instance for up to seven days. If you don't manually start your DB instance after seven days, your DB instance is automatically started. This way, it doesn't fall behind any required maintenance updates`

Comment: yes...i thinkdestroying is a good idea then